Nonunital weak operator closed self adjoit subalgebra has a projection that acts like an identity operator?
Let $A$ be weak operator closed self adjoint subalgebra of the bounded operators for a Hilbert space $H$(may not have identity so cannot use usual von neumann alegbra properties). I have shown that if $p, q \in A$ are projections, then $p \vee q \in A$ where we are considering the ordering of projections. I was told that there exists a largest projection $p$ in $A$ that acts like an identity operator i.e. $Tp = pT = T$ for all $T \in A$.
Other than $I$, I cannot think of any projections that commute with an operator in $A$ and satisfy $Tp = pT = T$. I can think of projections that satisfy $pT = T$ by considering the norm closure of the image of $T$, but I am unsure if this projection will be even in $A$. I know that the norm closure of the projections in $A$ is clearly a subalgebra of $A$ since $A$ is norm closed. I can show that if I have a countable collection of projections $p_n$ in $A$, then I can define a sequence $p_1 \vee \ldots \vee p_n$ and show that it strong operator converges to $\bigvee p_n$(which will be in $A$ because $A$ is strong operator closed), but again I am having some issues. I think I am missing something in terms of the algebra aspect since my abstract algebra is quite weak.

You can use strong operator closedness to not only consider the join of countably many projections, but an arbitrary collection of projections. That is, if $I$ is an index set, and $p_i$ is a projection for all $i \in I$, then $\bigvee_{i \in I} p_i$ is the SOT-limit,
$$\bigvee_{i \in I} p_i = \lim_{I_0 \subset I} \bigvee_{i \in I_0} p_i$$
where $I_0$ is the net of finite subsets of $I$. So the join of arbitrarily many projections in $A$ will be in $A$ as well. In particular, by taking the join of all projections of $A$, you can show that there is a maximum projection $p \in A$. Note that for any projection $q \in A$, because $p \geq q$, we must have $pq = q = qp$.
Now, how to proceeds further at this point depends on what you know about WOT-closed self-adjoint subalgebras. For example, if you already know the fact such an algebra is norm-densely spanned by its projections (by applying functional calculus, say), then the result easily follows from $pq = q = qp$ for all projections $q \in A$ by taking linear combinations and then norm limits.

Also, for any $T \in A$, the projection onto the closure of the range of $T$ is actually in $A$, which is again a consequence of functional calculus.

Using the fact that these range projections are in $A$ is also enough to prove the result. Both of these methods rely on Borel functional calculus. If you haven’t seen that, an alternative way of proving the result is using the fact that every (not necessarily unital) $C^\ast$-algebra has an approximate identity. Then take the SOT-limit of the said approximate identity.

I am some what familiar with borel functional calculus. I understand everything up to "an algebra is norm-densely spanned by its projections". I know this holds for a Von Neumann algebra using borel functional calculus. Even if it's not unital, it is guarenteed that $\chi_S(T) \in A$ where $S$ is a borel subset of the spectrum of a normal operator? I know that $\chi_S(T)$ in double commutant of $T$, but we can't use this fact anymore $A = A''$.

Also is approximate identity the more "natural" way to do this? I am only used to dealing with unital C* algebras however it seems that the approximate identity seems perfect here

@3jiwiojr3 It’s not true that $\chi_S(T) \in A$ for all Borel $S \subset \sigma(T)$ in this case. For example, if you take $S = \sigma(T)$, then $\chi_S(T) = 1$, which is not assumed to be in $A$. However, this is true for all Borel subset $S \subset \sigma(T)$ which does not contain $0$, similar to how continuous functional calculus still works in nonunital $C^\ast$ algebras whenever the continuous function in question has value $0$ at origin. This is enough to prove both of the facts I mentioned.

@3jiwiojr3 I wouldn’t necessarily call it more “natural”. It depends on what you are familiar with. If you’re more used to dealing with the theory of abstract $C^\ast$ algebras, then using approximate identity seems the easier approach. If you’re more used to spectral theory, then using Borel functional calculus seems easier.
